# Error establishing a database connection mysqli_real_connect()

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'sitename'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1489

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'sitename'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1515

```
line 1489:mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );

line 1515:$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

Comment: Are you sure you MYSQL allows remote connections?

Comment: Sorry I Dont Know Much About Mysql,Can You Tell Me How To Check Remote Conntections?

Comment: **`mysql_connect()`** and **`mysqli_real_connect()`** in the same script???? Not a good idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I Didnt Edit Anything I Am Using Xampp

Comment: A wordpress tag would have been useful. I added one